# Apple Music change volume

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm integrating Apple Music on my ios app, and I want to change the volume programmatically.

I'm using:  `let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer` player.

But I found that this player doesn't have an API for changing volume.

Any solutions, please?

Comment: Why are you tagging 3 different programming languages? Which one are you actually using?

Comment: I'm creating a Flutter plugin and I'm using swift as programming language

Comment: Then why tag C#?

Comment: Programing language is not the main problem, my main problem is changing the player volume.

Comment: You can’t but you can let the user do it, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview?language=objc